# Creating code environment with \DeclareTCBListing from tcolorbox

Tags: listings, tcolorbox, minted, xparse

I intend to create a code environment to speed up and clean my TeX code. The idea is that it can be preceded by a 5mm space, a `section` and/or `subsection` and/or `subsubsection` also be optionally printed together in the same page using `minipage`.

So far I've got the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[fontsize=12pt]{fontsize}


% Code
\usepackage{shellesc, minted}
    \setminted
    {
        linenos,        % line number
        autogobble,     % line trim
        tabsize= 4,     % tab size
        obeytabs,       % tab alignment
        breaklines,     % break lines
    }
    \usemintedstyle{fruity}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{Background}{white!5!black}
\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}


\usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary
    {
        breakable,                  % allow page break
        minted, xparse, listings,   % code minted
    }
    \tcbset%
    {   every box/.style= {
        coltext=        white,      % text  color
        coltitle=       white,      % title color
        fonttitle=      \bfseries,  % title font
        opacityframe=   0,          % frame opacity
        colback=        Background, % background color
        colframe=       Background, % border     color
        width=          \linewidth, % Width
    }}

% code
\DeclareTCBListing{codeBox}
    { s t1 t2 t3 O{5mm} O{left=2.5em} m m }
    {
        before=
        {
            \vspace{#5}
            \IfBooleanF{#1}{\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\relax}
            \IfBooleanT{#2}{      \section{#8}\relax}
            \IfBooleanT{#3}{   \subsection{#8}\relax}
            \IfBooleanT{#4}{\subsubsection{#8}\relax}
        },
        \IfBooleanTF{#1}
            {breakable,}%
            {after= {\end{minipage}\relax},}%
        listing only,
        listing engine= minted,
        minted language= #7,
        minted options={},
        #6
    }


\begin{document}

%% Code breaks when using environment, but not when declaring
%% Outputs Error 1
%\begin{codeBox}{python}{env test}
%def hello(foo):
%   print(f"Hello world ${foo}", 1+1, True)
%\end{codeBox}

%% Code breaks if i try to insert a section before tcblisting
%% Outputs Error 2
% \section{before}

\begin{tcblisting}
{
    before=%
    {%
        \vspace{5mm}
        \noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \section{manual test}
    },
    after= {\end{minipage}},
    listing only,
    listing engine= minted,
    minted language= python,
    minted options={},
    left=2.5em,
}
def hello(foo):
    print(f"Hello world ${foo}", 1+1, True)
\end{tcblisting}

\section{after}

\end{document}
```

Since its implemented with minted, to compile, use the following command on a terminal in the file location: `lualatex --shell-escape ./*.tex`

The errors generated are as follows:

Error 1:

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 69.
<inserted text> 
\fi 
<*> ./Untitled.tex
```

Line 69: `\begin{codeBox}{python}{env test}`

Error 2:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\endminipage ...pagefalse \color@endgroup \egroup 
                                                  \expandafter \@iiiparbox \...

l.93 \end{tcblisting}
```

- Why is it not possible to add `\section{}` before `tcblisting` environment?
- What is going wrong with the declared environment `codeBox`?